# Creating an MDB table using VBA and ADO, how to automatically use UUID as the primary key?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a table in an mdb file.

Currently my function adds a autoincremented primary key.

Instead of sequential intergers, I would like new rows to be created using UUIDs.

Can this be done ?

Here is my currently working MDBCreateTable function.

```
Function MDBCreateTable(myPath As String, TableName As String, ColumnDefinition As String) As Boolean

    ' ColumnDefinition structure     Column1;;Datatype::Column2;;Datatype
    Dim Columns() As String
    Columns = Split(ColumnDefinition, "::")

    Dim xCat As ADOX.catalog
    Dim xTable As ADOX.Table

    'Instantiate the ADOX-object.
    Set xCat = New ADOX.catalog
    Set xTable = New ADOX.Table

    On Error GoTo Failed

    Dim ConnectionString As String
    ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & myPath & ";"
    xCat.ActiveConnection = ConnectionString

    'Name the table.
    xTable.Name = TableName
     'Create the field which also is the Primary Key (PK) field for the Table.
    xTable.Columns.Append "ID", adInteger
     'In order to access the properties we need to set the Parent Catalog.
    xTable.ParentCatalog = xCat
    xTable.Columns("ID").Properties("AutoIncrement").Value = True
     'Append the PK.
    xTable.Keys.Append "PrimaryKey", adKeyPrimary, "ID"

    For x = 0 To UBound(Columns)
        If inStB(Columns(x), ";;") Then
            Select Case Split(Columns(x), ";;")(1)
                Case "integer"
                    xTable.Columns.Append Split(Columns(x), ";;")(0), adInteger
                Case "decimal"
                    xTable.Columns.Append Split(Columns(x), ";;")(0), adNumeric
                Case "date"
                    xTable.Columns.Append Split(Columns(x), ";;")(0), adDate
                Case Else
                    xTable.Columns.Append Split(Columns(x), ";;")(0), adWChar
            End Select
        End If
    Next x

    xCat.Tables.Append xTable
    MDBCreateTable = True

Failed:
End Function
```

For the record, this function is based on the following forum thread

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/printthread.php?t=40365

and here is a text I found regarding using UUIDs as primary keys

https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439

Also, I am new to using MDB files, I currently store all my data in excel worksheets and this is my first attempt at using MDB files instead.

So I start at the creation of database files and next creation of tables.

(next I will create functions to read and write from the MDB file)
(also I will be moving to vb.net eventually, I hope the ADO api is similar in vb.net and that I am not learning it for nothing. I had a hard time choosing between DAO, ADO vs ADODB, in the end I picked at random, I think )
thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the *Type* of the field/column as seen [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1358037.aspx?How%20do%20I%20add%20a%20column%20of%20type%20GUID%20Replicate%20ID%20to%20a%20Access%20table%20using%20the%20Alter%20Table%20Add%20Column%20Statement) at the bottom:

```
ADODB.Connection cn = new ADODB.Connection(); 
ADOX.Column clx = new ADOX.Column();
ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog(); 
ADOX.Table tblnam;
cn.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient;cn.Open(sExternalDBConnectionString, "", "", 0); 
cat.ActiveConnection = cn;
clx.ParentCatalog = cat;
clx.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adGUID; 
clx.Name = "IDField";
clx.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = false; 
clx.Properties["Fixed Length"].Value = true;
clx.Properties["Jet OLEDB:AutoGenerate"].Value = true;clx.Properties["Jet OLEDB:Allow Zero Length"].Value = true; 
tblnam = cat.Tables[sExternalDBTableName];
tblnam.Columns.Append(clx, ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adGUID, 16);
cn.Close();
```